# Debug "print to file" print driver code

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, printing, driver

I would like to test a printer driver plugin that I am working on (learning as I go along), I am using the examples from [Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 8.1 Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e) .

To test, I attach WinDbg to the print spooler and get the debug messages.

That works if I create a printer on LPT1 or any other port

If I try attaching the printer to the "FILE:" port, none of the debug messages I have in the plugin get displayed - even though I am certain the functions I have get called.

How can I see debug messages when I print to "FILE:" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to see the debug messages from printing to the FILE: port, by ataching the debugger to the "`explorer.exe`" instead of the "`spoolsv.exe`"

Comment: what is FILE port? Is it a new port that i need to create. I am trying to not attach to spoolsv